# Radio buttons too wide

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, radio-button

Can someone help me with this problem. I have two radio buttons in View:

```
@Html.RadioButton("technology", "Basic") Basic
@Html.RadioButton("technology2", "Advanced") Advanced
```

And they are displayed like this:

[image]

Why are they displayed wide like that? Any ideas?

Comment: What CSS do you have?

Comment: That default CSS which was generated when I created new project (ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application).

Answer (score 1):

Load this page into Firefox and use Firebug to inspect it and see what CSS is being applied.
You can adjust the CSS right there in Firebug to figure out how you want it to look.
After you figure out the CSS you want to use, add it to your source file.

Answer (score 0):

Debug this element in in Chrome if even firefox and try to add `overflow: visible;`  to your css